# Windows 7 Shutdown Issue / ExitWindowsEx/AdjustTokenPrivileges

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shutdown

Hello to all stackoverflow great minds!! I need some explanation and suggestion on how to determine what have cause this problem. I hope nobody would be harass and will judge directly. If there are not clear here please be kind to reply.

I have an application that i am investigating right now. The application will shutdown the Windows if a power-off message was posted from one of its child processes.

Scenario:
When i start the application and post a power-off message nothing happens to windows only the application was exited. The second time I start the application then post again a power off message the windows shutdown or reboot depending on the condition i had send.

```
HANDLE  hToken;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES  tp;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,
    SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &(tp.Privileges[0].Luid));
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
if ( iApplicationProblemOccured == 1 ){
        ExitWindowsEx(EWX_FORCE | EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_POWEROFF, 0L);
    } else {
        if(wShutdownType != 1) {
            ExitWindowsEx(EWX_FORCE | EWX_REBOOT, 0L);
        } else {
            ExitWindowsEx(EWX_FORCE | EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_POWEROFF, 0L);
        }
    }
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, TRUE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
    ExitProcess(0);
```

The problem is why the execution of the  ExitWindowsEx from the first power off does not works?
I have checked the tokenpriveleges from the first poweroff but it was enabled.
I have also change the dwReason to planned in the ExitWindowsEx but nothing happens.
From what i read in
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx
if the return of ExitWindowsEx  is 0, it does not necessarily determines that the execution of windows shutdown will be successful because  the function will only initiate the shutdown process.
I am thinking that there is something process/services that blocks stops the windows shutdown process from the first power off..
Is there a way to debug the windows shutdown process after my application send the shutdown request?

I am hoping someone can help me with this issue!!
Thanks a lot..

Comment: You aren't checking any return values at all. How did you determine, that the Windows API calls succeeded? Your question would be better, if you removed all the unnecessary details. It is not relevant, how your application receives a shutdown request, or its topology.

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation .This is the original code from the application that i am investigating.. In my current testing here, I am debugging the code and place getters for the return value to check the returns. I had also used GetLastError() to determine if there are errors during the adjustment of token privilege and ExtiWindowsEx

Comment: I had also modified dwReason in  **ExitWindowsEx** by using this combination _SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_APPLICATION | SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_INSTALLATION | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED_

Comment: This is where i had referred for the reasons to shutdown https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376885(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `Because the function executes asynchronously, a nonzero return value indicates that the shutdown has been initiated. It does not indicate whether the shutdown will succeed. It is possible that the system, the user, or another application will abort the shutdown.` [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868.aspx)

Comment: Just for the other programmers that are encountering same issue i have found this  website http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/06/09/how-windows-shuts-down.aspx.

Comment: I will continue to update  this issue from what will be the result of my investigation.